# TypeScript: computed property key with constrained property name?

Tags: typescript

How to define a type with a computed property key with a constrained property name?

I made an enum to restrict the computed property key name choices. After that I made a type that allows either the property name or the computed property name.

The only way I got it working is with `[key: string]: string;`. But unfortunately, the computed property key name is not constrained to the `FormFields` enum.

```
enum FormFields {
  Email = "email",
  Password = "password",
}

type FormState = {
  email?: string;
  password?: string;
} & {
  [key: string]: string;
};
```

The way I am trying to implement it:

```
  const [form, setForm] = React.useState<FormState>({
    [FormFields.Email]: "",
    [FormFields.Password]: "",
  });

  const handleChange =
    (field: string) => (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      statePropertySetter<FormState>(
        { [e.target.name]: e.target.value },
        setForm
      );
    };

function statePropertySetter<T>(
  properties: T,
  stateUpdater: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>
) {
  stateUpdater((prevState: T) => ({
    ...prevState,
    ...properties,
  }));
}
```

I tried the following:

```
[key in FormFields]: string;
```

but this produced the following error:

> argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormState'.
> Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ email: string; password: string; }': email, password

Comment: `e.target.name` is a string. There is no way (AFAIK) to type it more stringently so you will need to do some appropriate work to convince the compiler that it is a member of the enum. Honestly IMO you're tilting at windmills with this anyway. You are adding a **lot** of complexity to your code for very little gain in type-safety. The DOM could give you *anything* at runtime, you ***will*** need to do runtime data verification: layering on a bunch of compile-time checks that don't actually do anything isn't helping you.

Comment: @JaredSmith I know, its overcomplex but this project is for learning and will serve as a place I can always reference to remember about for instance implementing generic type parameters. Do you mean doing type assertions to convince the compiler?

Comment: Yes. You will need to use a cast, or a user-defined type guard (aka a type predicate function), or something along those lines. If that's your goal don't use this as an example. Do something practical instead. Implement some data structures like a linked list or a binary tree (something not in the JS standard lib). Make them generic containers over the types of the things they hold. Don't practice bad habits like needless convolution or security theatre. Plus you get to learn more about data structures that way, and that's **always** a good thing.

Comment: Sorry if I'm coming across a little strongly here. I have a couple of co-workers who are, to put it bluntly, static typing fetishists. I know more about both type systems in general and Typescript specifically than they do (I'm semi-officially the SME in that space in my org) and I *constantly* have to pull them back from writing code like that in your question in production React code.

Comment: @JaredSmith I understand, no need to apologize I am thankful for your advice. You are right. I would not use this in production code or collaborate with people writing code like this. I will also google to understand the terms new to me in your comment, like type guards, binary tree/linked list and generic containers.

Comment: I don't know that this is the best introduction but [this one seems ok](https://dev.to/ricardo_borges/series/13370), and here's a bit about [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: Does this question depend on react?  If so you might want to tag it as such.  If not, please consider removing the example code's dependency on react.